# Why won't Typescript declare an unassigned variable?

Tags: typescript

Typescript compiles the following class with unassigned variable `world`:

```
class Hello {
  world: string;
}
```

to the following javascript *without* a declaration for variable `world`:

```
var Hello = (function () {
    function Hello() {
    }
    return Hello;
}());
```

But if you assign the variable to *anything*:

```
class Hello {
  world: string = undefined;
}
```

Then the declaration for the variable *is* included:

```
var Hello = (function () {
    function Hello() {
        this.world = undefined;
    }
    return Hello;
}());
```

Why won't Typescript add the declaration for `world` when no default value is assigned to it?

For example the following code:

```
new Hello().hasOwnProperty('world')
```

Returns `false` for the first case, but `true` for the second case. I actually do expect it to be true, because I've declared it in Typescript (although I didn't assign a value to it).

I also couldn't find a compiler option for this. Did I miss anything? Why does Typescript do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript just adds "syntactic sugar" on top of javascript, but at the end it's compiled to js and is depended on what's supported in js.

If you look at the [es6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) you'll see that there's no equivalent for declaring members the way it's done in typescript, member definition only happens inside the constructor.

Because of that there's no way to add the members unless you assign a value to them.
There are only two options :

1. Add to the prototype
2. Add to the instance

Methods are added to the prototype, but members are only added to the instance which happens in the constructor.

---

#### Edit

There are a few ways in which you can solve this, the most straightforward one is to manually assign `undefined` to all members in the constructor (as you already mentioned), but that doesn't scale well..

You can "automate" it in several ways, one of which is to use [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).  In your case though you'll need to use two decorators one for [the class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) and one for [the members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators).

Here's something that seems to be working:

```
type RegistryEntry = {
    property: string;
    defaultValue: any;
}
const Registry = new Map<string, RegistryEntry[]>();

function AssignDefaultValues(target: any) {
    var original = target;

    function construct(constructor, args) {
        var c: any = function () {
            return constructor.apply(this, args);;
        }

        c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
        const instance = new c();

        const entries = Registry.get(original.name) || [];

        entries.forEach(entry => {
            instance[entry.property] = entry.defaultValue;
        });

        return instance;
    }

    var f: any = function (...args) {
        return construct(original, args);
    }

    f.prototype = original.prototype;
    return f;
}

function DeclareProperty(defaultValue: any = undefined) {
    return function (target: any, property: string) {
        const className = target.constructor.name;
        let entries: RegistryEntry[];

        if (Registry.has(className)) {
            entries = Registry.get(className);
        } else {
            entries = [];
            Registry.set(className, entries);
        }

        entries.push({
            property,
            defaultValue
        });
    }
}

@AssignDefaultValues
class Hello {
    @DeclareProperty()
    world: string;
}

let hello = new Hello();
console.log(hello.hasOwnProperty("world")); // true
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20RegistryEntry%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20Registry%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20RegistryEntry%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20AssignDefaultValues(target%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20original%20%3D%20target%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20construct(constructor%2C%20args)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20c%3A%20any%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20constructor.apply(this%2C%20args)%3B%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c.prototype%20%3D%20constructor.prototype%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20instance%20%3D%20new%20c()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20entries%20%3D%20Registry.get(original.name)%20%7C%7C%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entries.forEach(entry%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance%5Bentry.property%5D%20%3D%20entry.defaultValue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20instance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20f%3A%20any%20%3D%20function%20(...args)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20construct(original%2C%20args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20f.prototype%20%3D%20original.prototype%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20DeclareProperty(defaultValue%3A%20any%20%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20className%20%3D%20target.constructor.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20entries%3A%20RegistryEntry%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(Registry.has(className))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entries%20%3D%20Registry.get(className)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entries%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Registry.set(className%2C%20entries)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entries.push(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20property%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20defaultValue%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40AssignDefaultValues%0D%0Aclass%20Hello%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40DeclareProperty()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20world%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20hello%20%3D%20new%20Hello()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(hello.hasOwnProperty(%22world%22))%3B%20%2F%2F%20true))

It's a long solution, but it seems to be doing the job.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Couldn't Typescript assign undefined to all unassigned members by default? I'd like to avoid having to assign all members to undefined myself.

Comment: Why is that needed? Javascript will return `undefined` if the property doesn't exist, so doing `hello.world` will return `undefined` whether you've set the member to `undefined` or you've done nothing.

Comment: For example when I 'd like to know if my object has a property `world`. In my case I'm binding my model to the view with Knockout, which currently crashes because the property being bound to does not exist (aka is not assigned to...). You could argue of course if the implementation of Knockout is correct, but it does make sense to me.

Comment: I've never used Knockout, but can you add the code that binds the model to knockout to your question?

Comment: The knockout example is added to the question. It crashes because of the absence of the `ipsum` property (declared in Typescript but unassigned, so missing)

Comment: I see, check my revised answer for a possible solution for your problem

Comment: Wow, that indeed also solves the problem. According to the docs however, decorators are still experimental and I don't know if annotating every property is strictly better than assigning every property. I did learn something new today though :-)

Comment: You can do similar things with factory functions which create the instances and then assign the default values, but you'll need this registry anyhow.